# Problematic access to internet via wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wifi-driver

I bought an asus laptop with windows 8.1 and it has an issue when accessing internet via wifi . When accessing internet via ethernet everything loads fine on my browsers but when accessing via wifi: on chrome it often prints `ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED` or loads the page falsely ,  on firefox also prints an error ,even evernote fails to sync most of the times.

I tried unistalling the wifi drivers and reinstalling them but this issue remains.Any suggestions for this  frustrating problem. Thnx in advance.

Comment: [How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill. Thnx 4 the reply, I tried those steps , problem still seems to be there .

Comment: I don't think you tried all those steps in less than 2 minutes :/

Comment: @DavidPostill. I've crossed these solutions before :D . Also worth mentioning, I often configure my router and its wireless settings and my other devices never had any problem ,its this laptop which no matter how I configure the wireless settings on my router , the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my Asus laptop, for which I downloaded a driver update by looking online for my Wi-Fi chipset. It has reduced the frequency of the problem, but not eliminated it. A workaround I have found is to use the hardware button combination to switch on Airplane Mode; waiting for around 5 seconds and turning it off.

If you can, try using a Linux variant(ubuntu, etc) to confirm the root cause to be a software issue, which I haven't been able to do owing to space constraints.

Possibly a DNS server change to Google Public DNS or Open DNS could work

Comment: Thank you, that is a helpful feedback.I assume we have the same problem. I tried now and done couple of tests on my ubuntu which is running on a virtual box and admittedly from some queries I've done in google and opening pages I didn't face any problem in contrast on windows in which on my first query I entered a webpage and it had a problem.It might be that ubuntu doesn't face any issues or it has a better responce on these connections issues,re-establishing new ones. The funny thing is that Asus supports windows :P .

Comment: Well, Windows is a temperamental beast :P You could try to adjust proxy servers though, to OpenDNS or Google Public DNS

Comment: :P (y) agreed. I changed to Google Public DNS both IPv4 and IPv6 DNS servers and from some tests I didn't saw any issues I hope it solved the problem.

Comment: Well that's amazing, lucky you :P